# Split Number every nth position from the last

Tags: javascript

I have a number like this.

```
const number = 123456789;
```

I'd like to split it like `[1, 2345, 6789]` or `['1','2345','6789']`;

I've found `match()` with `Regex`.

```
console.log(number.toString().match(/.{1,4}/g));
```

It returns `['1234', '5678', '9']`

It looks pretty well done, but It's a reversed result that I want.

so, I made a tricky flow for this.

```
console.log(number.toString().split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,4}/g));
```

So, Now I get `['9876','5432','1']`

But it doesn't still being what I want.

```
console.log(
  number.toString().split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,4}/g).map(str=>str.split('').reverse().join('')).reverse());
```

Finally, I can get the result that I want.

But It looks pretty **ugly and inefficient.**

Even I think it shouldn't be used on the code.

So, my question is **How can I split a number every `nth` position efficiently?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make the code *shorter*, match 1 to 4 characters while using negative lookahead for 0 or more groups of `.{4}`, followed by `$` (the end of the string):

```js
const number = 123456789;
console.log(
  number.toString().match(/.{1,4}(?=(?:.{4})*$)/g)
);
```

But this requires, on every match, checking the number of characters from the match to the end of the string, which is an `O(n ^ 2)` process overall. To be more efficient, check the length of the string first, and use modulo to take as many characters as needed to make the remaining string have a length of a multiple of 4:

```js
const str = String(123456789);
const index = str.length % 4;
const firstItem = str.slice(0, index);
const items = str.slice(index).match(/\d{4}/g);
items.unshift(firstItem);
console.log(items);
```

This code is longer, but it runs in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could match by groups from 1 to 4 characters and take look forward to a group of four.

```js
var number =  123456789,
    parts = number.toString().match(/.{1,4}(?=(.{4})*$)/g);

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid splitting and reversing, another option might be to left-pad the number string until it is a multiple of the group size, match and trim back again:

```
>>> s.padStart(s.length + (4 - s.length % 4)).match(/(.{4})/g).map(s => s.trim())
[ '1', '2345', '6789' ]
```